# Ruby on Rails generators with new gemified plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, devise, rubygems, rails-generate

I'm attempting to create a new Rails 3 plugin gem which wraps around devise/devise_ldap_authenticatable for reusable drop in internal LDAP support.

I create the new plugin gem with:

```
rails plugin new <gem_name>
```

I then add the devise/devise_ldap_authenticatable gems to the .gemspec file and run `bundle`

In the devise instructions it says to generate the required files using its generators:

```
rails generate devise:install 
rails generate devise MODEL
```

However, in the directory where the plugin is generated I don't seem to be able to run `rails generate`.  Most gem plugin tutorials instruct you to just create the files manually.  Am I better off starting a new rails project, following the instructions in the temp project, then copying the files over to the plugin manually?  Is there something that I'm missing?  Can I run the generator script from the dummy instance?  What is the standard practice in this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I opted to forgo wrapping devise_ldap_authenticatable due to its relative simplicity.

The answer that I would go with in the future is to just to move files from a throwaway project.